# lucene errror: Indexing to directory 'c:/index'... adding 1234 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value cannot be null 1002 total milliseconds

Tags: java, apache, lucene, luke

```
package lucene;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.DateTools;
import org.apache.lucene.document.DateTools.Resolution;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;
public class Lucenetest {
//database connection
public static final String PATH = "C:/dbindex/index.txt";
private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:sqlserver://WMDENTW1\\SQLEXPRESS:1433;" + 
                    "database=FullTextDB;" + 
                    "user=root;" + 
                    "password=root123";
private static final String QUERY = "select FTID, ID, CLASSID, TEXT, PUBNOTICECONTENT, DOCUMENTCONTENT, contentSum_DE from METADATA_FULLTEXT";
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Lucenetest indexer = new Lucenetest();

//error here

***Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File(PATH).toPath());***

try {   
// Index Writer 
   Class . forName ( JDBC_DRIVER ). newInstance ();  

   Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL); 

   StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();  

   IndexWriterConfig  config  =  new  IndexWriterConfig ( analyzer );

   IndexWriter index writer =  new  IndexWriter ( indexDir ,  config );  

   System.out.println("Indexing to directory '" + indexDir + "'...");  

   int indexedDocumentCount = indexer.indexDocs1(indexWriter, conn);  

   index writer . close ();  

   System.out.println(indexedDocumentCount + " records have been indexed successfully");

} catch (Exception e) {  
   e.printStackTrace();  
} 
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
int indexDocs1(IndexWriter writer, Connection conn) throws Exception {  
  String sql = QUERY;  
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();  
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);  
  int i=0;
  while (rs.next()) {  
     Document d = new Document();  
 d.add(new StringField("FTID", rs.getString("FTID"), StringField.Store.YES));
 d.add(new StringField("ID", rs.getString("ID"), StringField.Store.YES));
 d.add(new StringField("CLASSID", rs.getString("CLASSID"), StringField.Store.YES));
 d.add(new StringField("TEXT", rs.getString("TEXT"), StringField.Store.YES));
 d.add(new StringField("PUBNOTICECONTENT", rs.getString("PUBNOTICECONTENT"), StringField.Store.YES));
 d.add(new StringField("DOCUMENTCONTENT", rs.getString("DOCUMENTCONTENT"), StringField.Store.YES));
 d.add(new StringField("contentSum_DE", rs.getString("contentSum_DE"), StringField.Store.YES));

     writer.addDocument(d);  
     i++;
 }  
  return i;
}


    private static void indexDocs(IndexWriter writer, Connection conn) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I am getting an exception, Indexing to directory:

> MMapDirectory@C:\dbindex lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4493d195'...
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value cannot be null at
>   org.apache.lucene.document.Field.(Field.java:238) at
>   org.apache.lucene.document.StringField.(StringField.java:61) at
>   lucene.Lucenetest.indexDocs1(Lucenetest.java:80) at
>   lucene.Lucenetest.main(Lucenetest.java:56)

Not really sure what I missed.

Comment: I am getting error as exception,
     Indexing to directory 'MMapDirectory@C:\dbindex lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@4493d195'...
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value cannot be null
     at org.apache.lucene.document.Field.<init>(Field.java:238)
     at org.apache.lucene.document.StringField.<init>(StringField.java:61)
     at lucene.Lucenetest.indexDocs1(Lucenetest.java:80)
     at lucene.Lucenetest.main(Lucenetest.java:56)  ...............  
    Not really sure what I missed

Answer (score 0):

Where you have marked this exception occurring in your code doesn't make sense.  That exception is being thrown within your `IndexDocs1` method.

`StringField` and `TextField` will both throw an IllegalArgumentException if the value (or field name) are null.  When importing from a nullable field in your database, you should check for null values and either skip the field, or replace it with a default value (using a default value is very useful if you want to be able to query for nulls).

Also:  Your `Directory` should be a directory.  The line:

```
Directory indexDir = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/dbindex/index.txt").toPath());
```

will create a new *directory* called "index.txt", not a file.  If such a file already exists, then that line *will* throw a `FileAlreadyExistsException`.

Comment: confused: Forget about all these things.. make it clear what are you trying to say...better if you write and show in my code

Comment: Not sure how to make it more clear.  You need to check for null values when building a document.  Simple as that.